# Comodo Dragon browser does not open pdf files

Tags: browser, pdf, chromium

I am using Comodo Dragon browser on Windows 8.1 and whenever I open a pdf file it automatically prompts me to choose a location for saving the file, instead of opening it within it as I wish. How may I change that?

For people that are not aware of this browser it's a Chromium based one (if it helps).

Comment: Come on people. Only 9 views? Due to low rep I cannot start a bounty on this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now called Cromodo, and acts very much like Chrome, follow these steps:

1. Click on the 3 horizontal bars (customize and control Chromodo).
2. Select Settings in the drop menu.
3. Click on the hyperlink (in blue) Show advanced settings.
4. Under Download, uncheck mark the box of Ask where to save each file before downloading.
5. Exit the Setting page.

And that should do it. If it was not working yet, just exit Chromodo and restart the browser once more.

Answer (score 1):

you must download Adobe reader and install it. Then you open Dragon and type `chrome://plugins/`
there you should see **Adobe Reader** - Version .... Click Enable below and also check Always allowed and that's it.

Comment: But why though? I have foxit and win8 default reader already installed, plus chrome already works with pdfs and komodo is in fact a different compilation of chromium

Comment: Is it now working or not? Don't know if it works also with foxit. And really don't know why it works this way, I just use Dragon

Comment: I am not currently home to test it, but when I do I will let you know. I was looking for a more simpler solution (not installing adobe's bloatware) but if there is nothing else that can help I suppose I will end up doing that.